# How to verify the get request is pulling in non empty string?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using our API to bring in 2 strings and add it to the DefaultRequestHeaders.

Very rarely, one or both of the strings are empty.

I want to apply some logic to the get request to check if they are empty or not.

If it is empty I want to wait a few seconds and try it again.

If after 5 attempts its still empty I want to throw the error.

I have looked up doing a few things, but I am still new to .Net so I am learning.

```
get
            {
                if (_itemClient != null)
                {
                    return _itemClient;
                }
                _itemClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Username", GetSystemParmValue<string>(SystemParameterKey.USERNAME));
                _itemClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Password", GetSystemParmValue<string>(SystemParameterKey.PASSWORD, true));

                return _itemClient;
            }
```

The problem I am running into is where to place this logic and how to apply it since its getting the information from system parameters.

Comment: With you current code you will either always return _itemClient or you will receive a null reference exception. For a string you can  check if IsNullOrEmpty String.IsNullOrEmpty https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if I understood what your trying to accomplish, can you please try to explain the problem that your having? The "wait to see if some variables will appear in the request header" doesn't make any sense to me and the code you've posted will either not modify the `_itemClient` or throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: I want to add logic in here to prevent the Null reference Exception. I am just puzzled how.

Comment: If they are empty, wait a few moments and try again to get the strings if its still empty Repeat the retry attempts up to 5 times After 5 tries, throw an exception and fail the call

Answer (score 1):

The following code will set the headers if ItemClient is not null using the Safe Navigation Operator.

Jerry Nixon has a great post on this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/

```
get
{  

                    _itemClient?.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Username", GetSystemParmValue<string>(SystemParameterKey.USERNAME));
                    _itemClient?.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Password", GetSystemParmValue<string>(SystemParameterKey.PASSWORD, true));

                    return _itemClient;
}
```

Comment: This is great, and what I am looking for, would this also work if the string was empty? Also I one of the request I got for this project was to put in logic to try it again if it was null or empty 5 times, and then fail the request after the 5th try. What I am trying to wrap my head around is to get the items and then check that they are not empty or null, wait a few seconds and then try again X amount of times.